# Sculpting fingers problems

Tags: sculpting, remesh

I separately sculpted the hands and fingers for a model, then joined mesh with the body and did voxel remesh in sculpt mode.

Then the problem appears:
[image: fingers.blend] The vertices of separate fingers kind of merge with each other in a messed up way, where there should be no mesh. There seems to be not enough space between the fingers.

Are there ways to fix this? Is my sculpting workflow wrong?

Happy about any help!!

Comment: it must have happened when you remeshed because the fingers were too close to each others, you need to correct thatin sculpt mode for example

Comment: The simplest way would be to try to run voxel remesh again with higher precision. However it may not be possible as you would need way too small voxels to make it work.. another solution would be just to take sculpting, select some brush, use dyntopo and tweak it a little with it, nothing too hard if it is just those 3 places + other hand

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind for next time!